# CSS grid: how to automatically size all columns to widest column?

Tags: css, css-grid

This is easiest to explain with an example:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(80px, 1fr));
}

.grid>div {
  background-color: yellow;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>foo</div>
  <div>foo bar</div>
  <div>eg ergerg</div>
  <div>fo eagro</div>
  <div>4ergearg ergearg er</div>
  <div>earg erg</div>
  <div>bverbr</div>
  <div> eargerg </div>
</div>
```

I want to size *all* the columns such that they're the same width as the widest column, in this case the one that says "4ergearg ergearg er".

I don't know its width, thus I don't know what to replace that `80px` with. `min-content`, `max-content`, and `auto` don't seem to work.

In other words, i want to stretch the columns to prevent the content from overflowing:

[image]

Comment: so you want to stretch that column and all the other with it?

Comment: Bascally, **you can't** without Javascript.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes. They should all be the same width.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'd be OK with some JS if it ran fast, but... the JS for this seems like it'd be quite ridiculous; I don't even know how many columns will fit!

Comment: I don't think there is a clean CSS solution (even a hacky one I don't think so)